# Filling color in svg image

Tags: python, svg, python-imaging-library

I have an svg file in this format:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48">
  <path d="M11.45 43.25Q9.5 43.25 8.125 41.875Q6.75 40.5 6.75 38.55V19.7Q6.75 18.6 7.25 17.6Q7.75 16.6 8.65 15.95L21.15 6.55Q21.8 6.1 22.55 5.85Q23.3 5.6 24 5.6Q24.75 5.6 25.475 5.85Q26.2 6.1 26.85 6.55L39.35 15.95Q40.25 16.65 40.775 17.625Q41.3 18.6 41.3 19.7V38.55Q41.3 40.5 39.9 41.875Q38.5 43.25 36.55 43.25H28.3V27.7H19.7V43.25Z"/>
</svg>
```

This vector image looks like this:

[image: an svg image of a "home" icon]

#### To fill the SVG svg's all "black" places (path) with solid color of specified hex code I used this:

***Example***: `'svg42.svg'` to be filled with solid color `'#00bbaa'`

```py
import io

from PIL import Image
from cairosvg import svg2png
from lxml import etree


def svg2image(file: str, color: str, width: int, height: int):
        with open(f'{path}', 'r') as f:
        svg_data = f.read().encode('utf-8')

    root = etree.fromstring(svg_data)
    tree = etree.ElementTree(root)

    root.attrib["fill"] = color

    for path in root.iter('path'):
        path.attrib["fill"] = color

    imgdata = io.BytesIO()
    tree.write(imgdata)

    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(svg2png(bytestring=imgdata.getvalue(), output_width=width, output_height=height)))

    return img
```

#### Problem:

when trying to fill the color in a more complex svg, it shows no effect on the output:

```
<svg width="989" height="875" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xml:space="preserve" overflow="hidden"><defs><clipPath id="clip0"><rect x="902" y="586" width="989" height="875"/></clipPath></defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#clip0)" transform="translate(-902 -586)"><rect x="902" y="586" width="639" height="652" fill="#ED7D31"/>
        <rect x="1252" y="810" width="639" height="651" fill="#4472C4"/></g></svg>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean by *"filling"* with #00bbaa. What will be filled - the white areas? The black areas?

Comment: You've described the problem, but haven't shared any code. What have you tried so far? What are you struggling with exactly? Loading the .svg? Changing the color of the element? Converting the image to a bitmap? Please share your work and be specific.

Comment: @Grismar I have updated the question again. Is it fine now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hardcoded the names of the structure of the XML file. In the first file, the data is in an element called `path`, so you use `root.iter('path')`.

However, in the second file, there is no element `path` in the XML, so the loop over it is over an empty iterator. If you really want to color all elements in the given color, you should not give an optional filter in the loop.

```
for path in root.iter():
    path.attrib['fill'] = color
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import io

from PIL import Image
from cairosvg import svg2png
from lxml import etree


def svg2image(file: str, color: str, width: int, height: int):
    with open(f'{file}', 'r') as f:
        svg_data = f.read()

    root = etree.fromstring(svg_data)
    tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
    root.attrib["fill"] = color
    imgdata = io.BytesIO()
    tree.write(imgdata)

    img = svg2png(bytestring=imgdata.getvalue(), output_width=width, output_height=height)
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img))

    return img
```

### Edit:

this was the answer I found to my original question, but it is not very efficient (nor applicable) for the edited question